# Beginner C++ - Trouble using global constants in a header file

Tags: c++, class, types, global-variables

Yet another Scrabble project question... This is a simple one.

It seems I am having trouble getting my global constants recognized:

My board.h:
http://pastebin.com/7a5Uyvb8

Errors returned:

```
1>C:\Users\Francisco\Documents\FEUP\1A2S\PROG\projecto3\projecto3\Board.h(34): error:     variable "TOTAL_ROWS" is not a type name
1>      vector< vector<Cell> > _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS , vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS));
1>
1>main.cpp
1>compilation aborted for .\Game.cpp (code 2)
1>Board.cpp
1>.\Board.h(34): error: variable "TOTAL_ROWS" is not a type name
1>      vector< vector<Cell> > _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS , vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS));
1>                                     ^
1>
```

Why does this happen? Why is the compiler expecting types?

Thanks for your time!

EDIT:

*Disregard my previous edit...*
This is my default constructor:
    Board::Board()
    {
             _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, vector(TOTAL_COLUMNS));
    }

I get the following error.

```
1>.\Board.cpp(16): error: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
1>       _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS));
1>       ^
```

Why does this happen?

---

I managed to solve all the problems with my file. I used

```
Board::Board() :
     _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS))
     {}
```

instead. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Please show us the header file

Comment: The header file in question is in my post. The pastebin link. It is rather large, so I uploaded it over there.

Comment: The error you show is on line (34).  However, the board.h file you link to only goes to line (30).  You'll need to help us understand exactly where the error is.  My best guess, however, will be in the answers in a minute.

Comment: My mistake. I took out the comment on top, I'll correct that in a minute. -- Done. Sorry for my idiotic mistake.

Comment: The header is not too large, just put it in so people don't have to switch around

Comment: The new linker error is because when you say `= 15` on your extern declarations you're effectively saying to the compiler "Oh I lied, it's not really extern and you should define space for the variable right here". Try removing the `= 15` and make sure that you have a non-extern copy of that line in exactly one of the source files.

Comment: Note that utilizing `using` in a header file is almost always a bad idea as it can bring names into the global namespace in any other file that includes that header. This can cause unexpected collisions and/or unexplained behavior. Better is to qualify your string and vector with `std::` like `std::vector`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way that is written, you are defining a function called _matrix that returns a vector.  So `TOTAL_ROWS` is expected to be a type name, since it is being parsed as a paramter type.  I assume what you are trying to do is define a variable called _matrix that *is* a vector.

What you want to do is leave off the constructor, and initialize the variable inside your constructor.  Only constant integral values can be initialized in the body of the class, at least in the current version of the standard.

Leaving off the unimportant parts:

```
  Board() : _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS)) { }

private:
  vector< vector<Cell> > _matrix;
```

Note that this is just an example.  Presumably you have an implementation file with an actual body for `Board()`, and you should put the initialization there rather than directly in the header or you'll get errors.  The important thing is that you should not do it when you declare `_matrix` initially.

---

For your new question, `extern const unsigned int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 15;` defines `TOTAL_COLUMNS` every time Board.h is included by a file.  Constant variables at namespace scope have internal linkage by default, so if you leave off the `extern` you will be okay.

In general, if the variable isn't constant, you take an approach similar to the one for `_matrix`.  You leave off the initialization in the header, and then inside an implemenation file put it back on:

board.h:
    `extern const int TOTAL_COLUMNS;`

board.cpp:
    `extern const int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 15;`

Answer (score 2):

You try to initialize the vector on it's definition, which is not the correct way to do this for object variables, the correct way is this:

```
extern const unsigned int TOTAL_ROWS = 15;
extern const unsigned int TOTAL_COLUMNS = 15;
class Board
{
public:
        Board() : _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS)) {}
private:
        vector< vector<Cell> > _matrix;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

In your header file, I see:

```
private:
    vector< vector<Cell> > _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS , vector<Cell>(TOTAL_COLUMNS));
```

This seems to be declaring a private member variable, `_matrix`, and is apparently an effort to call the constructor for `_matrix` at the same time.  You cannot call the constructor in this way.

Remember that your header file may be included in MANY program files.
As a result, headers should not contain execution instructions (certain exceptions exist, such as inline methods and templates).  You never know where the header will be included, so you never know where the code in a headerfile will appear.

It is good advice to write your header files so that they are safe to be included *anywhere*.

If you want to continue this code, I suggest:
The constructor of Board() should construct the member variable explicitly:

```
Board::Board() :
    _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS, .....);
    // This will call the matrix constructor ONLY when the Board constructor is called.
{
}
```

Then the Board constructor should be called, but ONLY in a `.cpp` file, not in a `.h` file.

Comment: In fact headers *must* contain the definitions of inline and template methods.

Comment: That is not what I meant to do. I meant to make `_matrix` a vector of vectors with TOTAL_COLUMNS * TOTAL_ROWS dimension. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: @Mark B:  don't confuse the beginner by introducing inline stuff.  Beginners need to know that header files should not include processing instructions (except when they really, really need to).

Comment: I would recommend against confusing beginners by lying to them, personally.  You make a lot of extremely strong statements.

Answer (score 1):

> This is my default constructor:
>
> Board::Board() { _matrix(TOTAL_ROWS,
>   vector(TOTAL_COLUMNS)); }
>
> I get the following error. [ .... ]

You did not follow the examples and syntax provided by @Dennis Zickefoose, @KillianDS, and myself.

Please re-read our answers and study our code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call a constructor in the header file (or any code for that matter).

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand.

Comment: While I understand what you are trying to say, your answer like it is formulated now is wrong in so many ways...